# Excel: setting the color of a cell to another

Tags: excel, colors, formatting, conditional-statements

How do I determine the color of a cell equal to another, example:
A4 is then C2 is cyan color cyan.
A2 is then C2 orange color is orange.
[image]

Comment: You can't alter the colour of the cell with a formula. You can get the colour of another cell by writing your own VBA function but if you want to change the colour you have to use a macro which cannot be called like a function. All a function can do is return a value, it cannot change any worksheet properties such as formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no excel-formula to get you the color of a cell, nor is there one, to set the color of a different one.

However, you can make a function to get the color of a specific cell - or, like in my example, the color of the function-calling cell:

```
Public Function GetColor()
    Dim rng As Range

    If TypeName(Application.Caller) = "Range" Then
        Set rng = Application.Caller
    End If
    GetColor = rng.Cells.Interior.Color
End Function
```

Now you might, think, ok then I modify this, just to SET the color too. But no - does not work that way. In order to change a cells color, you would have to use `Worksheet_Change` event and setup each cell to the long value inside them as their color.

```
Target.Interior.Color = Target.Value
```

Would be the line for that, when using `Worksheet_Change`.

You can of course use `ColorIndex` as well - just adapt accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

here is some C# code, maybe it could be helpful to you:

```
xlSheet.Range["A10", "A10"].Interior.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Cyan);
xlSheet.Range["C10", "C10"].Interior.Color = xlSheet.Range["A10", "A10"].Interior.Color;
```